# Why jQuery UI tooltip creates another div for title?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

this is my jQuery UI code for tooltip:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).tooltip({
        track:true  
    });
});
```

and this my title code for wordpress :

```
<div class="contentImage" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?>
</div>
```

it works and it shows the tooltip, but my problem is when i hover my mouse over the content image, although it shows the tooltip but it creates a div with title value and shows it under the footer of my template. what is my problem?thanks!

Comment: Looks like a z-index issue, if you can check the css please.

Comment: I would expect this behavior if you had not included the jquery-ui css file properly.

Comment: thanks for your responsing, i have edited my jquery-ui css file and this my propeties:.ui-tooltip {
 padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  max-width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #54c5d0;
  font: 12px 'Segoe UI';
 transition-timing-function: ease;
 border-radius:200px
} Should i add anymore property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to copy css-rule for class ***ui-helper-hidden-accessible*** and ***ui-helper-hidden*** from ***jquery-ui.structure.css*** file:

```
.ui-helper-hidden {
   display: none;
}
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
   border: 0;
   clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
   height: 1px;
   margin: -1px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: thanks , i forgot to copy all styles properties for my tootip